# join excel and access using Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, ms-access, linq-to-sql

In access table & excel join i have status column in access table and want the mismatched query where Account number are not equal and status =yes. I have tried using And operator but not working.
xl means from excel, ac means from access.

```
 var missing = xl.Where(x => !ac.Any(a => a.AccountNo == x.AccountNo));
```

The above query runs but i want status =="yes" also

```
string xlConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textselect.Text + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'";
        var xlConn = new OleDbConnection(xlConnStr);
        var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [mer_SVC$]", xlConn);
        var xlDT = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(xlDT);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = xlDT;
        List<GIS> xl = xlDT.AsEnumerable().Select(g => new GIS()
        {
            AccountNo = g.Field<string>("Account No"),
            MeterNo = g.Field<string>("Meter No#"),
            Mobile = g.Field<string>("Mobile "),
            Name = g.Field<string>(" Name"),
            GeoCode = g.Field<string>("Geo Code"),
            Welaiyh = g.Field<string>("Welaiyh"),
            Area = g.Field<string>("Area"),
            Region = g.Field<string>("Region"),               
        }).ToList();
        string acConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = F:\RAEC\RAECOEXCEL\Customer\Customer.mdb;";
        var acConn = new OleDbConnection(acConnStr);
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM GIS", acConn);
        var acDT = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(acDT);
        List<GIS1> ac = acDT.AsEnumerable().Select(g => new GIS1()
        {
            AccountNo = g.Field<string>("AccountNo"),
            Stat=g.Field<string>("Status")               
        }).ToList();            
        var missing = xl.Where(x => !ac.Any(a => a.AccountNo == x.AccountNo && a.Stat == "Yes"));    
        DataTable dt = xlDT.Clone();
        int count = 0;     
        foreach (var m in missing)
        {
            var n = dt.NewRow();
            n["Account No"] = m.AccountNo;
            n["Meter No#"] = m.MeterNo;
            n["Mobile "] = m.Mobile;
            n[" Name"] = m.Name;
            n["Geo Code"] = m.GeoCode;
            n["Welaiyh"] = m.Welaiyh;
            n["Area"] = m.Area;
            n["Region"] = m.Region;          
            dt.Rows.Add(n);
            count++;
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use *Join* clause for selecting non-missing values that you want to exclude.

```
var nonMissing = xl.Join(ac, EXC => EXC.AccountNo,   // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
                          ACS => ACS.AccountNo,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
                          (exc, acs) => new { EXC = exc, ACS = acs }).Where(x=>x.ACS.Status =="Yes");
```

With adding select clause end of this query, you can get the account numbers that you want to exclude. After that, all you need to do is simply selecting account numbers that is not contained in the list of non-missing account numbers.

Comment: Thank you.I have added Select(i => new {i.ACS.AccountNo,i.EXC.Mobile });

Answer (score 0):

Just add && statement with status condition.

```
var missing = xl.Where(x => !ac.Any(a => a.AccountNo == x.AccountNo && a.Status=="Yes"));
```

Comment: Add some sample data, and desired output.

Comment: I have tried this query and get the desired results when exported excel sheet in acces. SELECT [1111].[Account No], GIS.Status
FROM 1111 LEFT JOIN GIS ON [1111].[Account No] = GIS.AccountNo
WHERE ((((GIS.Status)="Yes") OR (GIS.AccountNo  Is Null)));